# Question about free resolution of an abelian group $H$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology

In Hatcher's Algebraic Topology book on page 193 he defines a free resolution of an abelian group $H$ to be an exact sequence of the from

$... \rightarrow F_2 \rightarrow F_1 \rightarrow F_0 \rightarrow H \rightarrow 0$

where each $F_n$ is a free.

Later, in the second paragraph of page 195 he allows $F_0$ to be a free *abelian* group. My problem here is that free abelian groups are not necessarily free groups.

> What is going on here?

Comment: Are you sure that “abelian” is not implied on page 193?

Comment: In my edition he doesn't say "free group" he just says "free". As the context is Abelian groups, he **means** free Abelian group.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I see, this makes sense.

Comment: A more general context resolutions make sense is $R$ modules for $R$ a commutative ring and abelian groups are used here precisely because they are modules for $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: Lord Shark the Unknown is right. I therefore edited your question to make clear what Hatcher really said: I replaced "each $F_n$ is a free group" by the original "each $F_n$ free".

Answer (score 0):

Hatcher means free as a $\mathbf Z$-module, which is to say that there is a basis, much in the sense of linear algebra.

This is common, for example in the discussion of homology one would say the abelian group freely generated by simplices etc.